# How can I call a function defined in a module with the same name as an attribute in the same module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If an attribute of a module is binded to a function which is defined in the same module with the same name as the attribute, how can I invoke the function directly from outside the module?

For example, `builtins.__import__` attribute is binded to `builtins.__import__` function by default.

If I rebind `builtins.__import__` attribute  to a function different from `builtins.__import__` function,

- how shall I invoke the new function by  the `builtins.__import__` attribute? Treat the `builtins.__import__` attribute as if it were a function, and make a call to it like `builtins.__import__(argument)`?
- how can I invoke the `builtins.__import__` function, if it is hidden by the `builtins.__import__` attribute?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Sure, why else would you bind a different function to that name? 2. You probably can't, if you want to access it *don't replace it*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, technically speaking, functions don't have names - there is no such a thing as 'function `a`', there is only a property/attribute/argument `a` pointing to a function (in memory).  Thus, unless you know the original function's location in memory - and that's (greatly simplified) what properties/variables represent, (wrapped) pointers - it will be lost for you. How can you find something if you don't know where to look (except manually by going bit by bit through the memory and trying to identify the structure you're looking for) and when you don't know the structure of it (because if you knew you could just recreate the function instead of searching for it)?

In fact, Python is usually smart enough to release the memory of any object that loses its reference count, otherwise a lot of Python would cease to work (or would create memory sinkholes within first seconds of operation) so if the `builtin.__import__` function has no other references than that (and to my knowledge it doesn't in standard CPython), it will be gone forever (for the duration of the current process) once you overwrite it to point to some other function.

Granted, given the importance of the function in question, I'd bet there are still references to it a level or two deeper so it probably doesn't get garbage collected, but finding a different 'route' to the function would be a time consuming task way out of SO answer scope.

If you were hoping to use this fact to build a 'sandboxed Python' - don't. Many have tried before and failed because you should never underestimate the time some people are willing to devote to find a workaround. Just run your Python instances in disposable VMs and live a carefree life (until somebody really, really dedicated finds a way to break out of that as well).